# Evaluate $ \int\frac{1}{(3x+5)(x-2)^2(x^2+6)(x^2+x+1)^2} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, systems-of-equations, partial-fractions

A person in another forum answered me with a method that I had never seen, I understand how it works except for the end where he gives me suggestions on how to solve it, it's been months and I still don't understand what I have to do to get the last ignconites.

Look at the answer of Shambhu Bhat
https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-to-evaluate-the-integral-of-int-frac-1-3x-5-x-2-2-x-2-6-x-2-x-1-2-dx-Is-it-possible-to-do-any-tricks-before-or-in-the-partial-fractions-themselves-1

I tried to follow Shambhu's suggestions, but I only get this, I also tried with the other values but the result is the same.
$ \begin{array}{l}\begin{array}{l}-------------------------------------------------\\
\left[\frac{6561}{3450799}=A\right]\left[\frac{?}{?}=B\right]\left[\frac{1}{5390}=C\right]\left[\frac{557}{3795950}=D\right]\left[-\frac{191}{3795950}=E\right]\left[\frac{?}{?}=F\right]\left[\frac{?}{?}=G\right]\left[\frac{36}{26269}=H\right]\left[\frac{185}{26269}=I\right]\\
-------------------------------------------------\end{array}\end{array} $

$ \frac{1}{\left(3x+5\right)\left(x-2\right)^2\left(x^2+6\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2}=\frac{A}{\left(3x+5\right)}+\frac{B}{\left(x-2\right)}+\frac{C}{\left(x-2\right)^2}+\frac{Dx+E}{\left(x^2+6\right)}+\frac{Fx+G}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)}+\frac{Hx+I}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2} $

$\frac{1}{\left(3x+5\right)\left(x-2\right)^2\left(x^2+6\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}=\frac{A\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(3x+5\right)}+\frac{B\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(x-2\right)}+\frac{C\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(x-2\right)^2}+\frac{\left(Dx+E\right)\left(x^2+x+1\right)}{\left(x^2+6\right)}+Fx+G+\frac{Hx+I}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)} $

$ \left[x=0\right] $

$ \frac{1}{\left(3\left(0\right)+5\right)\left(0-2\right)^2\left(0^2+6\right)\left(0^2+0+1\right)}=\frac{A\left(0^2+0+1\right)}{\left(3\left(0\right)+5\right)}+\frac{B\left(0^2+0+1\right)}{\left(0-2\right)}+\frac{C\left(0^2+0+1\right)}{\left(0-2\right)^2}+\frac{\left(D\left(0\right)+E\right)\left(0^2+0+1\right)}{\left(0^2+6\right)}+F\left(0\right)+G+\frac{H\left(0\right)+I}{\left(0^2+0+1\right)} $

$ \frac{1}{120}=\frac{A}{5}-\frac{B}{2}+\frac{C}{4}+\frac{E}{6}+G+I $

$ \frac{1}{120}=\frac{\frac{6561}{3450799}}{5}-\frac{B}{2}+\frac{\frac{1}{5390}}{4}+\frac{-\frac{191}{3795950}}{6}+G+\frac{185}{26269}\ ? $

there is nothing to compare there is not 1 single igconigta left, is anyone able to complete this person's method?

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition. There's no trick that I know of.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I know it is partial fractions, in the same question in the other forum I say so, my question is, what method is Shambhu using to solve the unknowns, if you try to do this by the traditional way of partial fractions you are going to take forever.

Comment: [Wolfram.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+1%2F%28%283x%2B5%29%28x-2%29%5E2%28x%5E2%2B6%29%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%5E2%29)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a simpler example:

$$\frac{1}{(3x+5)(x-2)^2} = \frac{A}{3x+5} + \frac{B}{x-2} + \frac{C}{(x-2)^2},$$ or
$$1 = (x-2)^2 A + (x-2)(3x+5)B + (3x+5)C.$$
Then if $x = 2$, all but the last term on the right hand side become zero, so
$$1 = 11C,$$ hence $C = 1/11$.  similarly, if $x = -5/3$, then all but the first term become zero, so
$$1 = (-\tfrac{5}{3} - 2)^2 A = \frac{121}{9}A,$$ hence $A = \frac{9}{121}$.  Unfortunately, there is no choice of $x$ such that the first and last terms simultaneously equal zero and let us solve for $B$.  However, this is not difficult to overcome; we can just choose a convenient value, say $x = 1$, and substitute the known values of $A$ and $C$:
$$1 = A - 8B + 8C = \frac{9}{121} - 8B + \frac{8}{11},$$ hence $B = -\frac{3}{121}$.

A similar idea applies to the more complicated rational function.  The only issue is that $x^2 + 6$ and $x^2 + x + 1$ have no real roots; but because the equation must identically hold, there is nothing prohibiting us from selecting an appropriate complex-valued root; e.g., $x = i \sqrt{6}$ will work.  For example:

$$\frac{1}{(3x+5)(x^2 + 6)} = \frac{A}{3x+5} + \frac{Dx + E}{x^2 + 6}$$ implies $$1 = (x^2 + 6)A + (3x+5)(Dx + E),$$ and the choice $x = -5/3$ this time gives $$1 = \frac{79}{9}A,$$ hence $A = \frac{9}{79}$.  Now the choice $x = i \sqrt{6}$ yields $$1 = (3\sqrt{6} i + 5)(E + i \sqrt{6} D) = (5E - 18D) + (5 \sqrt{6} D + 3 \sqrt{6} E)i.$$  The imaginary part must be zero, so $5D + 3E = 0$, and the real part must be $1$, so $5E - 18D = 1$.  This gives $D = -\frac{3}{79}$, $E = \frac{5}{79}$.

The key idea is to first solve for the easy coefficients--the ones that have a linear factor in the denominator.  Then use these to solve for the higher-order terms.

Comment: A trick to find $B$ in your example above... $\frac {1}{3x+5} = \frac {A}{3x+5}(x-2)^2 + (x-2)B +  C$... Take the derivative of both sides, and evaluate at $x = 2.$  $-\frac {3}{(3x+5)^2} = -\frac{3A}{(3x+5)^2}(x-2) + \frac {A}{(3x+5)}(x-2) + B \implies -\frac {3}{121} = B.$  Since you know that the "$A$" terms are going to evaluate to zero, you do not actually need to calculate these derivatives.

Comment: So much work by hand!  Why not:  *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{334 x+113}{86583 \left(x^2+x+1\right)}+\frac{557 \log
   \left(x^2+6\right)}{7591900}-\frac{46485 \log
   \left(x^2+x+1\right)}{237987806}-\frac{1}{5390 (x-2)}-\frac{809 \log
   (x-2)}{2075150}+\frac{2187 \log (3 x+5)}{3450799}-\frac{191 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}\right)}{3795950 \sqrt{6}}+\frac{3828995 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{356981709 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: oh that's how you solve with imaginary numbers, I get the idea and it's a little faster, but how I would apply that in this problem I'm going to try multiplying up and down x^2+x+1 and then turn the 0 into imaginary numbers and then do a comparison, I'll add another comment when I do that

Comment: still doesn't make sense to me, can you tell me what I should do? $ \left[x^2+x+1=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right] $

Comment: https://ibb.co/92GkV2W

Comment: @strikarsimen So if you pick one of those two roots as the value of $x$, how does the equation simplify?  I know it's very computational and tedious, but it is still easier than solving a system of equations in $9$ unknowns.  In any case, there is a point at which it is more important to understand the **process** than actually performing the computation by hand. You would not, for instance, find it useful to compute $352734178035823 \times 2357804972830478 \times 16831078382043294$ with only pencil and paper. You'd use a calculator because by now, you understand the process of multiplication.

Comment: @heropup I choose 1 of the roots? and replace in each 1 of x?
https://ibb.co/1KtwkwR

Comment: @strikarsimen You wrote $x = x + \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{ \sqrt{3}}{2}$, but instead, you need to write $$x = \frac{1}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$

Comment: @heropup I assume this is the idea? https://i.ibb.co/8mZ5Vm5/1.png